# JavaFx imageview can't resolve file error

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I've been struggling with this problem regarding JavaFx ImageView class. the code written in fxml

```
  <ImageView fitHeight="634.0" fitWidth="1204.0" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="83.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="-8.0">
     <image>
        <Image url="@\PCI%20logoRYB.png" />
     </image></ImageView>
```

and it keeps showing this error

```
Cannot resolve file '\PCI%20logoRYB.png'
```

I created all this using scene builder and the image is at the same place as the fxml file/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove \ from your url, like below. Image must be in the resources directory.

```
<ImageView fitHeight="634.0" fitWidth="1204.0" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="83.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="-8.0">
 <image>
    <Image url="@PCI%20logoRYB.png" />
 </image></ImageView>
```

Comment: nothing happened, same error....but strangely the image loaded when I run the code

Comment: Check your image file, maybe problem is in a extension of file. Try change to .PNG in url.

Comment: strangely it worked regardless of the error...when I press run the image loaded as a background...thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **`eclipse IDE`** after adding resources like images you need to clean your project to reload all new resource files which was added to project.

[image]

Comment: well no, I use Intelij but the problem anyways has been solved, thanks bro